# 2022 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Since one of our previous (and most active) moderators is no longer moderating for our site, we currently have a lack of active moderators and are considering to hold a new election relatively soon.

To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.

**Note**: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Currently, February 28th is the tentative date for such an election, starting with nominations, but only if we can get enough people willing to run for moderator positions.

Comment: 28 February is way too early. It is 15 February right now. What do you think? Also, has there been any announcement about what happened (or at least when it happened) to the other moderator? When I [search "nbro" on Meta](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=nbro) and sort from newest to oldest, the last thing I see is complaints about a question being deleted by nbro towards the end of December 2021.

Comment: @NikeDattani That date was suggested to me by the Community team. As far as nbro is concerned, nothing happened, he just decided he no longer wants to continue moderating.