# Announcement: Upcoming Moderator Election Planned for May 9

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

A while ago [we have already posted](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2863/1641) a check for potential interest in new members of our community becoming moderators. At the time there seemed to be relatively little interest, but it would be good regardless to get another moderator, since we have rather few active ones right now.

Therefore, the current plan is to start a **new moderator election** for [ai.stackexchange.com](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) on **May 9**.

Answer (score 1):

The community indeed needs at least 2 reasonably active moderators, so that when one isn't available there's the other (hopefully). Right now, Dennis is the only active one. I would love to see people that have always cared for the community (i.e. unconditionally and for at least 1-2 years) and have a good overall knowledge of the AI field to run for mod in the next elections.

In my view, the best people for this role right now are: Neil Slatter, Edoardo Guerriero or David Ireland (although he hasn't been so active recently). Hopefully, at least one of them is interested in the role. Otherwise, honestly, right now, I don't see another good person for this role, as I believe a mod should be

- an active user (visit the site at least 1 a day and handle issues)
- have a good knowledge of AI
- be reasonably patient
- someone that, over the years, really showed to care for the community and AI (e.g. by writing answers, asking for clarifications, closing clearly off-topic posts, voting, etc.), so not someone that comes here every once in a while with a cocky attitude showing that they know how our site works or should work
- know quite well the scope of our site (if you're not familiar with it at this point, I don't think you're prepared to be a mod!) and how Stack Exchange sites usually work
- have **not** gotten into heated discussions with other users (including [old] moderators, like me) or have been suspended for irregularities or poor contributions (here or somewhere else)

Essentially, a great mod for our community would be someone like Dennis himself, who meets all the criteria above.